# PHP: Unicode nodeValue?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, domdocument, nodevalue

I am trying to extract all the link text and hrefs from an HTML string, but the source string is Unicode, and nodeValue doesn't seem to cope with this?

```
$links = array();
$titles = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $str );
$hrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
    $links[] = $href->getAttribute("href");
    $titles[] = $href->nodeValue;
}
```

My source string looks like this:

```
<p><a href='uploads/root/tr_62.pdf'>Türkiye</a></p>
```

But my output for $titles[0] looks like this:

```
TÃ¼rkiye
```

How can I make nodeValue respect the Unicode characters?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: When you add `Header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` to your script (before first output), does it fix the problem?

Comment: I have a full HTML header on the page,
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
etc...

Comment: `DOMDocument` and all XML functions default to UTF-8 so they can handle Unicode just fine. From your output, it's your app the one that either uses some single-byte non-Unicode encoding or fails to declare its encoding (`<meta>` tag is mostly irrelevant, what counts is HTTP headers and of course actual content). /// Leave your PHP code apart by now. If you copy and paste a static `車`, does it print correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You much using mb_convert_encoding

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html_data  = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); 
$dom->loadHTML( $html_data  );
$hrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
    $links[] = $href->getAttribute("href");
    $titles[] = $href->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround that should by no means be necessary in a UTF-8 enabled app. It merely masks the underlying encoding misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, user Veve's comment answered my question.

The following line solves my issue:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, 'html-entities', 'utf-8' );
```

Comment: This is a copy Daniel's answer and it doesn't "solve" the issue, it hides it by converting everything to 7-bit US-ASCII.

Comment: Not strictly true, it's a copy of the answer linked to in Veve's comment, which Daniel and I both re-posted. I didn't see Daniels answer until after I submitted mine.

Comment: Fair enough. In any case, the idea of closing questions as exact duplicate is not having the same information spread everywhere (as it's just happened). Whatever, I don't think that question is actually the same. I believe you app may just not support UTF-8.